# Find point on line that has integer coordinates

Tags: geometry, integer-lattices

Given a 2D line e.g. `(3,10) -> (8.3,16.5)`, how can I find any point on that line that has has whole-number coordinates?

I can easily iteratively walk along one of the axis in integer steps, seeing if the value on the other axis is integer, but this is slow for very very long lines.

I think, in math-speak, I want to efficiently find all the lattice points between two points?

<sub>I mark this as homework because its literally hobby problems I'm inventing myself at home.  I don't recall much beyond high-school math anyway.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First find the slope of the line, using this formula:

$$\text{Slope of the line} = \frac{\text{Change in y}}{\text{Change in x}}$$

$$m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} = \frac{16.5-10}{8.3-3} = \frac{6.5}{5.3} = \frac{65}{53}$$

Now using this formula find the equation for the line:

$$y - y_1 = m(x-x_1)$$
$$y - 10 = \frac{65}{53}(x-3)$$
$$y = \frac{65x}{53} + \frac{530 - 195}{53}$$
$$y = \frac{65x + 335}{53}$$

Now $x$ can be any integer, but in order $y$ to be an integer $65x + 335$ needs to be divisible by $53$. In other words:

$$65x + 335 \equiv 0 \pmod{53}$$
$$65x \equiv -335 \pmod {53}$$
$$12x \equiv -70 \pmod {53}$$
$$6x \equiv -35 \equiv -88 \pmod {53}$$
$$3x \equiv -44 \pmod {53}$$
$$3x \equiv -150 \pmod {53}$$
$$x \equiv -50 \equiv 3 \pmod {53}$$

So for every $x=53k + 3; \forall k \in \mathbb{R}$, we have an integer point on the line that pass through the two initial points

So one example will be the point $(x,y) = (56,75)$

Comment: Hi... I did not under stand from 12x≡−70(mod53) on.please explain

Comment: @MadanRam Note that in modular arithmetics we can add the modulo to any any side of the equation and it won't change anything. But also we can divide both sides if they have a common divisor. (Note that if the common divisor divides modulo we need to divide it also). So we have:

$$12x \equiv -70 \pmod {53}$$

Now divide by 2 and since $2$ isn't divisor of 53 we don't divide the modulo. Also subtract the modulo from the right side, it doesn't change anything.

$$6x \equiv 88 \pmod 53$$

Repeat the same process again. Divide by 2 and add 53 twice to the right side.

$$3x \equiv -150 \pmod{53}$$

Comment: @MadanRam

Now at last divide by 3 and add 53 to the right side:

$$x \equiv -50 \equiv 3 \pmod {53}$$>

Is it clear now?

Comment: yes... Thank You @stefan4024

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-integer-point-line-segment-given-two-ends/ could help